# Windows installer transform file needed from an msi installation wizard

Tags: windows-installer

I need to know how to generate an mst file from an installation ,but it should take up all user inputs from installation.

Ie i click an msi and give some updates in installation,i have log file generated but how do i get mst file from Code or commandline(without any ORCA manual doing)

Comment: am trying to open msi installation wizards through C sharp code using wix
      i am not able to get the set up wizards where i give user   
      inputs i get just welcome dialog finish repair but not other wizards

Comment: Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Full, ref parent);
                 fSession = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, true);
                  fSession.DoAction("LaunchConditions");
                fSession.DoAction("Setup_Dialog");

Comment: OR  i can even get all dialogs using   Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Full, ref parent);       
            fSession = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, false);  fSession.DoActionSequence("InstallUISequence");  but this case installation happens..but i do not want any installation..How can i skip or

Comment: I have added ActionStartEventHandler so that to enter inbetween dialogs..Now i need to get properties at runtime..ie public properties,how do i  get public properties names at run time,i have property names from Property table from msi ,but i dont get USERNAME,COMPANYNAME properties for a particular msi or any some other props for other msis from existed property table to get at run time

Comment: I am taking properties list from the link   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#feature_installation_options_properties                                                                             _browse property did not mention here,so added it manually in code,will there be any other properties that are not mentioned in the link ,can be changable from wizard other than custom or Client Speicific properties?

Comment: is there a way that we get database directly after user inputs from wizard using wix session   , session.database gives the original database ,it does  not update database from user inputs,but i can get properties by session["COMPANYNAME"],etc..so i have only option to  uopdate database myself using the session properties ..or is there a way that i get database directly within installUISequence...Note: i added Commit,but it wont update..i am escaping actual installation